# Interpreting regression coefficients based on Andrew Gelman's re-scaling method

Tags: regression, logistic, regression-coefficients, standardization, scales

I have two predictors in a binary logistic regression model: One binary and one continuous. My primary goal is to compare the coefficients of the two predictors within the same model.

I have come across Andrew Gelman's suggestion to standardize continuous regression input variables:

I) Original proposal (2008): divide continuous predictor by 2 SD

```
Original manuscript: 
http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/standardizing7.pdf
```

II) Updated recommendation (2009): divide continuous predictor by 1 SD AND re-code binary input values from (0,1) to (-1,+1)).

```
Updated recommendation (1 SD, recode binary):
http://andrewgelman.com/2009/06/09/standardization/
```

Proper interpretation of the resulting coefficients still is elusive to me:

SCENARIO 1: BOTH PREDICTORS ARE SIGNIFICANT IN THE SAME MODEL

Outcome: non-transformed binary Y
Continuous predictor: XCONT (divided by 1sd)
Binary predictor: XBIN (recoded to take values -1 or 1)

```
  > orfit1c=with(data=mat0, glm(YBIN~XCONT+XBIN, 
   family=binomial(link="logit")))
  > summary(orfit1c)

   Call:
   glm(formula = YBIN ~XCONT + XBIN, family = binomial(link = "logit"))

   Deviance Residuals: 
           Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
       -0.9842  -0.6001  -0.5481  -0.5481   1.9849  

       Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
        (Intercept)  -1.8197     0.1761 -10.331  < 2e-16 ***
        XCONT         0.3175     0.1190   2.667  0.00765 ** 
        XBIN          1.0845     0.3564   3.043  0.00234 ** 
        ---
       Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

       (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

       Null deviance: 398.99  on 409  degrees of freedom
       Residual deviance: 385.88  on 407  degrees of freedom
       AIC: 391.88
```

SCENARIO 2: NEITHER SIGNIFICANT IN SAME MODEL (BUT when they are entered separately in two different models, their coefficients are both significant)

```
       Call:
      glm(formula =YBIN2 ~ XCONT2 + XBIN2, family = binomial(link = 
       "logit"))

               Deviance Residuals: 
           Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
          -1.0090  -0.6265  -0.5795  -0.5795   1.9573  

            Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
       (Intercept)  -1.7562     0.1835  -9.570   <2e-16 ***
       XCONT2         0.2182     0.1318   1.656   0.0977 .  
       XBIN2        0.6063     0.3918   1.547   0.1218    
                         ---
       Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

          (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

          Null deviance: 398.99  on 409  degrees of freedom
          Residual deviance: 390.01  on 407  degrees of freedom
          AIC: 396.01
```

Question: 
For the original scaling method, it was explained that "a one-unit change in a continuous predictor covers two standard deviations of that predictor"

For the updated scaling method, am I correct in my interpretation of scenario #1 that:

(1) a one unit change in continuous predictor covers 1 standard deviation of the XCONT

(2) and this change in 1 SD in XCONT is equivalent to a 1 unit change (i.e. absence or presence) of the binary predictor (XBIN).

(3) accordingly, 1 SD change in XBIN predicts a 1 unit increase in YBIN whereas 1/3 unit increase in YCONT predicts a 1 unit increase in YBIN?

QUESTIONS

- Does interpretation outlined in 1-3 need any correction? As the binary outcome variable was not re-coded, can I still say that 1 unit change in X predicts a 1 unit change in binary outcome (0 or 1)?
- What else could be said about the results, specifically when I attempt to compare the two coefficients for the continuous and binary predictors?